# Play Store - Problems adding apk to the market

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I used **PhoneGap** to create my application

Now I made a `key.keystore` and uploaded it to phonegap site as shown here

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html

Now I downloaded `app-release.apk` and **decompiled** it using apk studio program to remove some permissions and recompiled it again.

The problem when I try to upload `app-release.apk` to the market it shows an Erorr

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a restricted certificate. You need to upload an APK signed with your own certificate.

I tried to resign the app again using this method

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

and when i try to upload it to the market it shows that Error

> Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again.

Any Help plz ?

I have been searching web for 3days now :O :S !

Comment: Well i guess the problem is that you let PhoneGap sign your app, then you decompile it and change some stuff. Either you just sign it yourself or you don't change anything after PhoneGap signed it.

Comment: I need to remove some permission so i decompile and recompile it again and when i try to sign `app-debug.apk` myself it shows an error `jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compres
sed size (expected 759 but got 761 bytes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somehow **solved** the mistake was

> when I change apk using apk studio to remove some permissions.

So I gone along with this
https://github.com/amirudin/build/wiki/Android-Signing

and downloaded `app-release.apk` and uploaded it to the market and it worked

however **I still need to remove some permissions** from the app :(

any help how to do that whithout affecting apk ?!

**Edit:**

to customize app permisions u need to set the`config.xml` inside app folder like this example :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  id        = "com.brilliantapp.seb7a2015"
  versionCode="7"
  version   = "1.2">
  <name>Seb7a</name>
  <description>
seb7a app helps u calculate zekr  </description>
  <author href="www.fb.com/DrOs96" email="Drusama2@gmail.com">
Osama Soliman
  </author>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
  <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
  <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="21" />
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
  <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
  <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
  <gap:platform name="android" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/144.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/192.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icon/android/64.png" />
 </widget>
```

**And this is a very useful program** http://configap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions on your app from the config.xml

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features